# VB.NET WinForms ListView doesn't display column headers

Tags: vb.net

I have below code in my Form Load event handler but the ListView doesn't show any column headers.
I want the column headers to be displayed. Any ideas?

```
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C1", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C2", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C3", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C4", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C5", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C6", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C7", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C8", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C9", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    lstBatch.Columns.Add("C10", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add

```
lstBatch.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
```